# Why am I getting this Warning: Can only update a mounted or mounting component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am getting this warning:

> Warning: Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually
>   means you called setState, replaceState, or forceUpdate on an
>   unmounted component.  This is a no-op.
>
> Please check the code for the QuantityCounter component.

This happens when I put my QuantityCounter component within my ProductCardScreen component (so when I make it a child component to this particular parent component).  On the previous page where it is also being used within a different parent component this does not happen though.

If I comment out the code within my componentDidMount() function (which is in QuantityCounter) then I don't get the warning message but my QuantityCounter component no longer works.

```
   constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {total: 0};
   }

componentDidMount() {
        AsyncStorage.getItem(this.props.data.productId.toString()).then((resultCount) => {
            if (resultCount !== null) {
                this.setState({
                    total: parseInt(resultCount)
                });
            } else  {
                this.setState({
                    total: 0
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

I have seen others ask about this warning online but none of the answers I have seen so far have helped.  I am assuming the child component is mounting before the parent component, but I am not sure.  Does anyone know how to get rid of a warning message like this?  How do I check if a component is unmounted?

Comment: Could you add the constructor please?

Comment: It might be because your component is mounted, then unmounted, and then mounted again.
The callback is fired during the unmounted phase, it can't set the state.

Comment: Since isMounted is depreciated now what is the best method for checking if the component is unmounted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Gabriel Blue I was able to understand that I need to make my check within the AsyncStorage and not wrap it around it like I had previously tried to do.  Here is what worked for me:

```
componentDidMount() {
    AsyncStorage.getItem(this.props.data.productId.toString()).then((resultCount) => {
        if (resultCount !== null && this.refs.quantityCounter) {
            this.setState({
                total: parseInt(resultCount)
            });
        } else if (this.refs.quantityCounter)  {
            this.setState({
                total: 0
            });
        }
    });
}
```

and for the HTML I added the ref tag to the outer most view:

```
<View ref="quantityCounter" style={styles.counterContainer}>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Ideally, any callbacks should be canceled in componentWillUnmount, prior to unmounting.

or

> Just set a _isMounted property to true in componentDidMount and set it to false in componentWillUnmount, and use this variable to check your component’s status.

[source](https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html)

Comment: I tried this and I would pass the _isMounted variable down to the child component and then I would check to make sure it was true before running the AsyncStorage code but the problem I ran into was it was true the first time around then it would be false and then true again (_isMounted variable) but the first time it's true my code fires off and doesn't stop so the next time that it's unmounted in the parent my child component code finishes and I get that warning.  Is there a way around this??

Comment: No, the child should have it's own `_isMounted`

Comment: Yeah, but it's the parent component that's being rendered twice so what would I need to do with the child's _isMounted?  The child's code is causing the error but it's firing at the wrong time because the parent is rendering too many times.  Shouldn't I have my child component wait on the parent somehow?  Though I don't know how because the parent's _isMounted is true and false at different times....

Comment: If the parent unmount, it will unmount the child too ... the important thing is that the `_isMounted` is true when `setState`

Comment: The child's AsyncStorage code is in the componentDidMount() function so it shouldn't fire if the child is unmounted right?  I think the problem is the parent is mounted at first (therefore so is the child) then the parent becomes unmounted for a second but the child's Asynchronous code already fired from when it was first mounted and when it finishes its unmounted temporarily.  What can you do about an asynchronous call that has already been previously fired?

Comment: No, ajax call starts when componentDidMount, but at the times it ends, the component is not mounted anymore ...

Answer (score 0):

I think your component is waiting for some data and gets unmounted before the data arrives.I have faced the same problem and solved it when I went through react docs official page [isMounted is an Antipattern](https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html).